# Undefined error inside ngrx reducer in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, state, ngrx

I am having an issue within my application at the moment where I get hte following error from within a couple of my reducers. I put breakpoints onto the line in question and there doesn't seem to be any issue so I am a bit confused. The error I get is:

```
ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at exports.usersUIReducer (usersUI.reducer.ts:14)
```

Here is the relevant code:

app.module

```
//Instantiate the Angular Object
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ChartsModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: APP_DI_CONFIG.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
        }),
        StoreModule.provideStore({
            reportExceptionsReducer,
            reportExceptionFormDefaultsReducer,
            reportExceptionsModelReducer,
            reportExceptionUIReducer,
            usersReducer,
            usersUIReducer
        }),
        routing
    ],
.......
```

UserDashboardComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../../services/authentication.service";
import { UserService } from "../../services/users/user.service";
import { User } from "../../classes/User.class";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { CHANGE_USERS_FILTERS, POPULATE_USERS } from "../../state/actions/actions";

@Component({
    selector: 'user-dashboard',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: '/app/views/users/users-dashboard.component.html'
})

export class UsersDashboardComponent {
    protected users: Array<User>;
    protected payload: Object;
    protected viewState: Object = {
        usersLoaded: false as boolean
    };
    protected activeUsersConfig: Object = {
        title: 'Users',
        showEdit: true as Boolean,
        showDelete: true as Boolean
    };


    constructor(
       private  _userService: UserService,
       private _authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
       private _store: Store<any>
    ) {
        this._store.select('usersReducer')
            .subscribe((users) => {
                this.users = users;
            });

        this._store.select('usersUIReducer')
            .subscribe((payload) => {
                this.payload = payload;
                if(!this._authenticationService.isSuper()) {
                    this.payload.account = this._authenticationService.accountId
                }
            });

        this.getUsers();
    }


    getUsers(): void {
        this._userService.getUsers(this.payload)
            .subscribe((response) => {
                this._store.dispatch({ type: POPULATE_USERS, payload : {users: response.extras.Users}});
                this.viewState.usersLoaded = true;
                //this.payload.maxItems = response.Users.maxItems;
            });
    }

    paginationChange(pageNum): void {
        this.viewState.usersLoaded = false;
        const offset = pageNum * this.payload.limit;
        this._store.dispatch({ type: CHANGE_USERS_FILTERS, payload: { offset }});
        this.getUsers();
    }
}
```

and the reducer

```
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { CHANGE_USERS_FILTERS } from "../../actions/actions";

const initialState = {
    account: undefined as number,
    limit: 1 as number,
    maxItems: 10 as number,
    offset: 0 as number
};

export const usersUIReducer = (state: any = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case CHANGE_USERS_FILTERS :
            return Object.assign({}, ...state,
                action.payload
            );
        default :
            return state;
    }
};
```

Is my implementation of ngrx correct as far as other more experienced users can see? I am unsure as to why I am getting an error and literally don't know where to start!

Thanks

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in sample code with plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting this error because you have not exporting an interface to your State. Also, I don't the point of setting `account: undefined` even though you are saying it is a number.

You should do something like:

```
export interface State {
    account: number,
    limit: 1 number,
    maxItems: number,
    offset: number
}

export const initialState: State = {
    account: 0,
    limit: 1,
    maxItems: 0,
    offset: 0
};
```